# How do I install Ubuntu on the C Drive without losing any data from the other drives?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

This is the first time I am installing Linux. 
I have Windows 7 on my C drive. I want to just format the C drive and then install Linux on the C drive only. So how can I install it on only the one drive (partition) replacing Windows 7?

When installing it is using the complete hard disk space.

Comment: Just install and choose the erase Windows option. Please don't ask questions with obvious answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `C:` drive does not translate to Linux partition structure. However, when installing, select manual partition setup, and select the existing partition that you want to format. Set that as mount point `/`, and make sure you allocate some of the drive for your SWAP area.

Comment: Hello Macey.Thanx for answer.Can u please Help me with video File how to install.It would be very kind of u if u could post me with Video Link

Comment: Try this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ